# Character encoding on Windows 7 with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, delphi, windows-7, character-encoding

Earlier I developed an application in Delphi 7 which connects to an MSSQL server.
On Windows 7 some characters`(ő, ű)` are wrong it displays `o` and `u`.
The collation of the MSSQL is good, the regional settings on the client are good (including the settings of the non-unicode programs).
I use the UniDAC component for the database connection.

I think the program can't read the regional settings properly (I don't know why, maybe because of a deprecated windows API) and the component sets the character encoding to the default.

Could somebody help me how to solve this problem. Is there any way maybe to set the character encoding manually for the connection?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Delphi 7 does not support unicode.

You need to use a Delphi version that supports Unicode (Delphi 2009) uses them by default.

See: [Working with Unicode strings in Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281223/working-with-unicode-strings-in-delphi-7)
for some help, but I doubt your db-driver for Delphi-7 will support wide strings.