# Sendmessage with WM_COPYDATA from vb6 to delphi is garbled

Tags: delphi, vb6, delphi-7, sendmessage, wm-copydata

i am sending data to a delphi app using WM_COPYDATA from vb6 app. in my system which local is english, i receive the data correctly, but on another system with dutch local, the receive text is garbled.

the receiving app is the delphi, the code is

```
procedure TReceiverMainForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  copyDataType: TCopyDataType;
begin
  copyDataType := TCopyDataType(Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData);

  //Handle of the Sender
  mmoResult.Lines.Add(Format('WM_CopyData from: %d', [msg.From]));

  case copyDataType of
    cdtString: HandleCopyDataString(Msg.CopyDataStruct);
  end;

  //Send something back
  msg.Result := mmoResult.Lines.Count;
end;

procedure TReceiverMainForm.HandleCopyDataString(
  copyDataStruct: PCopyDataStruct);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := PChar(copyDataStruct.lpData);
  mmoResult.Lines.Add(s);
end;
```

**EDIT**

here is the vb6 code that is sending the data, the data am sending is string

```
Dim buf() As Byte
ReDim buf(1 To LenB(Message))
Call CopyMemory(buf(1), ByVal Message, Len(Message))
cds.dwData = 0
cds.cbData = Len(Message) + 1
cds.lpData = VarPtr(buf(1))
' Send the string.
Dim i As Long
i = SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COPYDATA, MainForm.hwnd, cds)
```

can anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you sending the data? Depending on the Delphi version you're using, the string could be interpreted as either unicode or ANSI. If you can confirm your VB code sending method, and Delphi version, I can do an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Deanna, it has Delphi 7 tag, so you're half a way closer ;-)

Comment: I saw that which implies that it's doing ANSI conversion. I still need to know the VB6 code before I can give a definite answer. [D7 seems to support wide chars but the UI doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2281327/588306).

Comment: @Deanna, about D7, it's like you say. You can declare `WideString`s but they won't be properly displayed, when you use built-in components whose are ANSI.

Comment: For beginning it makes sense to find out, which specific part of your data chain (including UI rendering) does not work. If your memo control does not support unicode, then could you try checking the following on the system with Dutch locale? Control Panel >   Regional and Language Options > the tab Administrative -> and make sure that "Language for non-Unicode programs" is Dutch. [look at 1-st screenshot here](http://www.sisulizer.com/localization/support/codepages-w7.shtml)

Comment: @Deanna i have added the vb6 code, that is sending the data. Note that the data am sending is normal us english charactster, which should not be a problem.

Comment: @stan i mentioned that i can receive the string in the delphi app correctly in my system with us-en locale. but mu dutch friend gets garbled or corrupted string

Comment: That code seems to be confusing byte length, character length, and character encodings. I'll try and do an answer shortly explaining what's happening.

Comment: Smith, exactly this is why I'm asking you 2 questions: unicode support in the component and language settings on the Windows with Dutch locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB strings are based on the COM `BSTR` string type, just like Delphi's `WideString` string type is.  A `BSTR` is a UTF-16 encoded Unicode string.  `LenB()` returns the number of bytes that a VB string occupies when converted to the local machine's current locale.  You are not taking that into account.  You are not copying the string bytes into your buffer correctly, and you are not setting the `cds.cbData` field to the correct value, either.  `Len()` returns the number of UTF-16 encoded characters in the String, whereas `LenB()` returns the number of bytes instead.  For an English string, `Len()` and `LenB()` will return the same value, but for a foriegn language that is not guaranteed.

I suggest you send the original VB Unicode encoded data as-is, and change your Delphi code to treat the incoming data as Unicode instead of Ansi like it is currently doing (`PChar` is Ansi in Delphi 7, but is Unicode in Delphi 2009+).

You also need to assign a unique value to the `cds.dwData` field.  `WM_COPYDATA` is used by the VCL for some of its own internal data, so you have to differentiate between your `WM_COPYDATA` messages and the VCL's messages.

Try this instead:

```
cds.dwData = RegisterWindowMessage("MyWMCopyData")
If cds.dwData <> 0 Then
  cds.cbData = Len(Message) * 2 ' characters are 2-bytes each
  cds.lpData = StrPtr(Message) ' access the string's character buffer directly
  ' Send the string. 
  Dim i As Long 
  i = SendMessage(lHwnd, WM_COPYDATA, MainForm.hwnd, cds) 
End If
```

.

```
var
  uMyWMCopyDataMsg: UINT = 0;

procedure TReceiverMainForm.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData); 
var 
  s: WideString; // you can use UnicodeString in D2009+ 
begin 
  if (uMyWMCopyDataMsg = 0) or (Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData <> uMyWMCopyDataMsg) then
  begin
    inherited;
    Exit;
  end;

  mmoResult.Lines.Add(Format('WM_CopyData from: %d', [msg.From])); 

  SetString(s, PWideChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData), Msg.CopyDataStruct.cbData div SizeOf(WideChar)); 
  mmoResult.Lines.Add(s); 

  msg.Result := mmoResult.Lines.Count; 
end; 

initialization
  uMyWMCopyDataMsg := RegisterWindowMessage('MyWMCopyData');
```

Comment: I don't understand then how it's working with English string, a char in a BSTR is always 2 bytes, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, a `BSTR` character is 2 bytes. However, in VB, passing a string `ByVal` converts it to Ansi for compatibility with `char`-based APIs. Thus, the code is converting the source string to Ansi when calling `CopyMemory()`, but it is using `Len()` instead of `LenB()` as the third parameter. That will only work correctly for single-byte languages, like English and Latin1-based languages.

Comment: thanks. But this still shouldn't be part of the problem since apart from far-eastern languages all of the ansi charsets are single byte per character. As far as I can tell, Dutch use latin-1 (win-1252).

Comment: @RemyLebeau am using d7, so how does this `s: WideString; // you can use UnicodeString in D2009+` apply? and regarding the `WM_COPYDATA` and VLC thing you talked about, does this example http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/wm_copydata.htm then becomes improper

Comment: If you use the code I showed that sends UTF-16 data instead of Ansi data then the use of `WideString` applies. And yes, that article is incomplete. It touches on the need to fill in the `cds.dwData` to identify `WM_COPYDATA` messages when sending them, but then ignores those identifiers when receiving the messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you help me with the receiving part of the vb6 code you posted in vb6? i cant get the message in delphi yet, so i need to debug it in vb6