# Delphi xml parser, why are some characters illegal - but many are not?

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, delphi-7

I've got a pretty basic xml, for which I made an interface through the automatic generator in delphi 7. This was working fine, until I ran into some odd characters being sent my way. As an example:

```
<AfasGetConnector>
  <Medewerker>
    <Afstortnummer>0032123</Afstortnummer>
    <Naam>Wiaëröóíïúáäâtè</Naam>
  </Medewerker>
</AfasGetConnector>
```

Pulling this into Firefox / IE will quickly tell you that there's illegal characters in it. To be exact: ë, é and ö will not be accepted. The rest however, are perfectly fine. (Even the capital versions Ë, É and Ö are fine)

This confuses me. Why would those 3 be illegal, but "ä" and most others be fine? Are there any others I should worry about?

The whole block is given to me in a CDATA,. so the initial transfer goes fine,. After that however, I need to pick through the individual "Medewerker" elements from the xml,. which are not encapsulated in the CDATA. Hence the issue.

Comment: Use unicode strings and the issues with accented chars go away. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281223/working-with-unicode-strings-in-delphi-7  Or even better port your project to a Unicode aware Delphi.

Comment: Note that JEDI has a number of Unicode components for pre-unicode delphi's.

Comment: Note: I have no control over what data the server sends, nor what format. And delphi 7's unicode support is somewhat limited without external libraries, is it not?

Comment: Did you visit the link I send you?

Comment: Yes, out of there the link : www.soft-gems.net/index.php/libs/unicode-library - seems most adequate,. but that will require some testing and research before we could use it.

Comment: D7 is quite capable of dealing with Unicode/UTF8 for this specific task without the need of any Unicode extensions/libraries. You did not provide any code. as long as you use `WideString` to hold your strings and use a XML parser which supports Unicode (e.g. MSXML) there is no problem.

Comment: Also, *"Pulling this into Firefox / IE will quickly tell you that there's illegal characters in it."* How did you "pull" it? did you save the XML file in Unicode/UTF8 format? does the XML has encoding headers?

Comment: The xml was saved locally as an utf-8.txt - the basic "issue" is the default delphi "XML Data Binding" generated with Delphi 7. Which uses the units  xmldom, XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

Comment: @Thomas, @kobik is asking about the XML headers, which you did not show. Anyway the answer to the problem is use `WideString` + MSXML.

Comment: I doubt D7 XML Data Binding supports Unicode (You did not mention that in your Q). You need to parse the XML yourself with IXMLDocument.

Comment: Those characters are fine. If you handle encoding correctly. Clearly you are not doing that.

Comment: There is no mention of Delphi's *XML Data Binding* in your post. You should edit to correct that omission. (Oh, maybe that's what you meant by *automated generator*? It's not clear from your question that the *generator* has anything to do with D7 from your phrasing.) While you're at it, post your XML header (the part that says `<?xml version="1.0"....?>`) as part of your XML snippet. Delphi's XML data binding for D7 should support Unicode as long as the XML declaration is correct in identifying it as UTF-8.

Comment: @kobik: Delphi's XML Data Binding is built on top of the `IXMLDocument`/`IXMLNode` interfaces, which support Unicode via a `DOMString` data type (an alias for `WideString`/`UnicodeString`), and always has.

Comment: Downvoted, because you did not provide enough detail to diagnose the issue. Have a look at the comments and edit the question to include the info requested. With that info your Q should be easily answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pulling this into Firefox / IE will quickly tell you that there's illegal characters in it.

Works fine for me.  Neither Firefox nor IE complain about the characters at all.

> This confuses me. Why would those 3 be illegal, but "ä" and most others be fine?

They are not illegal at all.  The XML specification allows *most* Unicode codepoints to be used (minus non-printable control characters, UTF-16 surrogates, and reserved codepoints).  All of the characters you have shown are legal.

> The whole block is given to me in a CDATA,. so the initial transfer goes fine,. After that however, I need to pick through the individual "Medewerker" elements from the xml,. which are not encapsulated in the CDATA. Hence the issue.

You are likely encountering an encoding mismatch between what the XML parser *thinks* the XML is encoded as, and what the XML is *actually* encoded as.  But since you have not provided the original *raw bytes* of the XML that was transferred, or the code that is trying to load and parse it, there is no way to know for sure what is actually happening.

Comment: Seems you're right,. Chrome doesn't mind the .xml if it's set to utf-8 in notepad++, but cries wolf when it's set to ANSI. I can't access the header right now,. but will have to check it on monday. I suspect in lacking a header delphi switches to the OS default rather than utf-8

Comment: If the XML is encoded in any charset *other than* UTF-8, the charset **must** be explicitly declared in the `encoding` attribute of the XML's prolog (except for UTF-16, where a BOM will suffice). UTF-8 is the default charset per the XML specification if no other charset is specified. In ANSI, characters `ë`, `é` and `ö` are likely being encoded as bytes 0xEB, 0xE9, and 0xF6, respectively. Those are not valid UTF-8 byte sequences, so any conformant XML parser should complain about them if UTF-8 is assumed. The same is true of the other characters shown (`ó` `í` `ï` `ú` `á` `ä` `â`).

Comment: SoapUI tells me the raw xml is utf-8,. however, AFAS does not send an encoding declaration in the xml. If i manually prefix the xml with an encoding as utf-8 - i still get the same error. If however I prefix the encoding as iso-8859-1, then everything works fine, without any need for character replacing.

Comment: @Thomas then SOAP UI is wrong and the XML really is encoded as ISO-8859-1, which explains why other systems are complaining about it. Without an explicit encoding declaration, UTF-8 must be assumed, and the bytes I showed are not valid UTF-8.